# Can I suppress alert "It looks like you are typing while in full screen" over iOS 12 fullscreen mode

Tags: ios, fullscreen

We are trying to show video over iOS safari with fullscreen mode (on later iOS 12, if the user enabled fullscreen mode API) and trying to allow the user to tap video screen to show some interactive effect over video (on fullscreen mode).

but when we tap screen several times on fullscreen mode, an  alert dialog of "It looks like you are typing while in fullscreen" was shown.

We want to avoid this message in some way.

We will appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Only a partial answer, but this was a solution for us:

The warning does **not** occur when the website is launched from the iOS home screen.

1. Open the web page in Safari
2. Tap the Share button
3. On the bottom row of icons, scroll over until you see *Add to Home Screen* and tap this.
4. A new shortcut will be added to the iOS homescreen
5. Launch from here and this warning message will not bother you

This is only a solution if you're in control of the iPad, or if your users are very compliant! But in our case this was all we needed. Hopefully some others will find the same.

Comment: On iPadOS 14.4, a WebApp launched from a home screen icon STILL renders the above warning. :-(  In spite of their noble intentions, Apple is killing me.